# Is there any way to build jobs with groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am passing Extended Choice Parameters from one job to another job, in the second job I am writing a groovy script to receive the parameter, and on basis of that parameter job must run multiple times in parallel. But there is no method available to build jobs in groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use build job from Jenkins Pipeline

```
build job: 'jobName',
            parameters:[[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'val1', value: '1' ],
                        [$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'SLAVE_NODE', label: 'slavename']
                       ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What if we have unknown number of a particular parameter and build job on the basis of number of parameter that executes in parallel

Comment: Your second part of the question is not clear. May be if you can post a separate question with more details . If number of parameters is unknown, you can still invoke the Build job and for the parameters that you are not passing, Jenkins would use the default value that was specified during Job Creation

Answer (score 1):

The [jenkins-pipeline](/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) that you added to your job is probably what you are searching for. With pipelines, you can define your build using a Groovy DSL.

You find an introduction in the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/). A (incomplete) list of steps available through plugins can be found in the [steps reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/).

P.S. Be warned that there are two different flavors: declarative pipelines (defined using the `pipeline` keyword) do not offer full freedom, but are a bit easier to handle regarding build failures and parse errors in your pipeline code. Scripted pipelines (with `node` steps allocating an executor) offer (nearly) the full power of Groovy.